# Python regex: match string only if it follows a curly brace

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
'\n    query {\n      allEmployees(first: 2) {\n        edges {\n          node {\n            name\n            department {\n              name\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n'
```

I want to match `allEmployees` only if it's after a curly brace. How can I do this using python. I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
import re
s = '\n    query {\n      allEmployees(first: 2) {\n        edges {\n          node {\n            name\n            department {\n              name\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n'
pattern = re.compile(r'\{[.]*(\w+)')
x = pattern.search(s)
```

The target result would be simply `"allEmployees"` (not including the curly brace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier to search on the string without newlines, if they aren't significant:

```
re.search(r'{.*?(\w+)', s.replace('\n', '')).groups()  # returns ('allEmployees',)
```